# Writing non blank cell to text file

Tags: excel, vba

So I have the following VBA code that writes to a CSV file, the problem is that the I have formula in a lot of the cells that return a blank value. The way the spreadsheet works will write put all of the valid results in the first rows leaving the rest blank. So I am trying to get

```
iLastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
iLastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

To count up to the last cell with data in as opposed to the last cell with a formula.

```
 Sub writeCSV()
    
    Dim iLastRow As Long
    Dim iLastCol As Long
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim Fullpath As String
    
    Fullpath = Worksheets("GUI").Range("f10")
    
    iLastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    iLastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Open Fullpath For Append As #1
            For i = 1 To iLastRow
                For j = 1 To iLastCol
                    If j <> iLastCol Then 'keep writing to same line
                        
                        Print #1, Cells(i, j),
                    Else 'end the line
                        Print #1, Cells(i, j)
                    End If
                Next j
            Next i
            'MsgBox "Failed to transfer " & iFail & " file(s).", iFail & " Transfer(s) Failed"
        Close #1
       
    End Sub
```

Comment: Is it always a rectangular area with non-blank cells? In other words, is it possible to have, say Cells(1,1)='A Value', Cells(1,2)='Another Value', Cells(2,1)=(blank), Cells(2,2)='Another Value'?

Comment: The data only actually used column A and B, I just wrote it like this but I could change it to write each col separately. But if data exists in one col in will exist in the other,

Answer (score 1):

### Last Row and Column Using the Find Method

- The `Find` method with its `LookIn` argument set to the `xlValues` parameter lets you ignore all blank cells, not only empty cells.

```vb
Sub LastRows()
    
    Dim lCell As Range
    ' Last Row
    Set lCell = Columns("A").Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
    If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' empty first column range
    Dim iLastRow As Long: iLastRow = lCell.Row
    ' Last Column
    Set lCell = Rows(1).Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
    If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' empty first row range
    Dim iLastCol As Long: iLastCol = lCell.Column
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said '*if data exists in one col it will exist in the other*' you can exit the outer loop as soon as you encounter the first blank cell:

```
For i = 1 To iLastRow
    If Cells(i,1)="" then
      Print #1,  ' if you still need the line terminator
      exit for
    End If
    For j = 1 To iLastCol
    ...
```